# Print np.array, formatação

Tags: python, numpy

Classe completa:

```
class Tupla:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras):
    self.keys = list(keys)
    self.palavras = list(palavras)
    self.op = dict(zip(self.keys, self.palavras))

def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.op[key]

def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tabela Completa: {self.op}'

def get_tupla(self, key):
    return f'Palavra: {self.op[key]}'
```

Onde keys e palavras são dois np.arrays.

```
dados = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/afons/Downloads/words.txt', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Criando array com todas as palavras do arquivo através do numpy e embaralhando

```
listaPalavras = np.array(dados.values)
np.random.shuffle(listaPalavras)
```

Criando array com as keys e embaralhando

```
listaIndices = np.array(range(len(listaPalavras)))
np.random.shuffle(listaIndices)
```

Criando a tabela de tuplas

```
tabela = Tupla(listaIndices, listaPalavras)
```

Comment: Para que criar o array se `pd.read_csv('C:/Users/afons/Downloads/words.txt', error_bad_lines=False)` lhe devolve um [`Dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Faça `print(dados)` lá vem toda a informação obtida do CSV.

Comment: Mas a questão é como imprimir o "self.op" completo que é um dict, onde junto as palavras do "dados" com uma key aleatória de outra lista. Na classe tupla ...

Answer (score 1):

A `listaPalavras`eh um objeto numpy e nao uma lista. Para voce conseguir imprimir `twine-twisting` voce tem que accessar os valores dessa coluna:

`print(listaPalavras['twine-twisting'])`

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso aqui: https://repl.it/repls/SubduedWellgroomedWebpages. Mesmo sendo um objeto numpy ele pode ser impresso como um todo sem ter que referenciar porções do objeto.

Comment: O exemplo que voce mandou no link eh um dicionario e um array simples sendo addicionado no numpy.array. Eu nao sei que tipo de estrutura de dados eh o seu `dados.values`.

Comment: Esse é ponto, estou a chamando atenção que não da responder ao autor da pergunta enquanto ele não a esclarecer e fornecer mais dados. A senhora pode estar correta, mas não dá para afirma qual o problema com 100% de certeza.

Comment: Pois é, quando eu referencio uma porção do objeto ele imprime de forma correta, o problema se da quando imprimo ele como um todo, vou reformular a pergunta, com a classe completa, acredito que alterando a função "__repr__(self):" seja possível, ou não ?